# Ransack OR queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ransack

I want to make a search for all fields that are NULL or have the value of -1 using ransack.

```
search({:param_name_null => 1 })
```

will give the nulls

```
search({:param_name_is_any => -1 })
```

will give the -1s

How do i make an OR between these two using ransack?
Thanks

Comment: ever find out how to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Ransack Issue #290](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/issues/290) explains that queries like this contain two separate conditions which need to be specified separately then combined.

I haven't tested this snippet but it, or something very much like it, should work:

```
.search(:m => 'or', :param_name_eq => -1, :param_name_null => true)
```